# Extract full link of a div element

Tags: sed, regex

I'm downloading episodes from a series, but I'm tired for joining in the site, copying the link and downloading it for each episode.

First, I join in the site and I get the HTML code. The code is big, but I'm interested in this in particular (it is where the link is)

```
    var e=Array(),d=1;e[1]='<div style="margin-left:7px"><object width="720" height="450" class="BLOG_video_class" id="BLOG_video-ee57f234e359092e" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/get_player"><param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="flashvars" value="flvurl=http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id%3Da87eff0521883521%26itag%3D5%26source%3Dblogger%26app%3Dblogger%26cmo%3Dsensitive_content%253Dyes%26ip%3D0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3D0%26expire%3D1400695090%26sparams%3Did,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire%26signature%3DAA6B72C5D9C12D461C7A0E3F59B2C208A7CDC82D.AE374E37E58A41191B10F30AA43BE42379DA6D5B%26key%3Dck2&amp;iurl=http://video.google.com/ThumbnailServer2?app%3Dblogger%26contentid%3Da87eff0521883521%26offsetms%3D5000%26itag%3Dw160%26sigh%3DaUKIa9j5GROOBShBybzlFhMGllc&amp;autoplay=0"><embed src="//www.youtube.com/get_player" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"width="720" height="450" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"flashvars="flvurl=http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id%3Da87eff0521883521%26itag%3D5%26source%3Dblogger%26app%3Dblogger%26cmo%3Dsensitive_content%253Dyes%26ip%3D0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3D0%26expire%3D1400695090%26sparams%3Did,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire%26signature%3DAA6B72C5D9C12D461C7A0E3F59B2C208A7CDC82D.AE374E37E58A41191B10F30AA43BE42379DA6D5B%26key%3Dck2&iurl=http://video.google.com/ThumbnailServer2?app%3Dblogger%26contentid%3Da87eff0521883521%26offsetms%3D5000%26itag%3Dw160%26sigh%3DaUKIa9j5GROOBShBybzlFhMGllc&autoplay=0"allowFullScreen="true" /></object></div>';e[2]='<div style="margin-left:7px"><iframe src="http://videosasd.com/play-zs-www30.zippyshare.com/v/94301695/file.html" width="720" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>';
```

Well, its a looong code, but I'm interested to get this. (There are 2 identical links, both work without the '&amp' in the end)

```
    http://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id%3Da87eff0521883521%26itag%3D5%26source%3Dblogger%26app%3Dblogger%26cmo%3Dsensitive_content%253Dyes%26ip%3D0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3D0%26expire%3D1400695090%26sparams%3Did,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire%26signature%3DAA6B72C5D9C12D461C7A0E3F59B2C208A7CDC82D.AE374E37E58A41191B10F30AA43BE42379DA6D5B%26key%3Dck2&amp
```

Now, I'm using this regEX (Note I'm noob with this, I test it and works)

```
\s*flvurl\s*=\s*(\"([^"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'">\s]+));*%26key%3Dck2&amp
```

And, in the terminal I use

```
wget -q -O - "serverlink" | sed -e "s/\s*flvurl\s*=\s*(\"([^"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'">\s]+));*%26key%3Dck2&amp//g"
```

I get error with `unexpected token`) '`

Does anyone know how I can fix it? (Or, maybe, someone knows a better regex to get the link from the first code box)

Comment: I think you should break down your regex into multiple small ones to find the error.

Comment: I learn something about put multiples # to break the regex, you mean that ?

Comment: No, I mean something like `wget -q -O - "serverlink" | sed -e "regex1" | sed -e "regex2" | sed -e "regex3"` and check the intermediate results.

Comment: post the input and expected output on your question.

Comment: What is `"serverlink"`? Is it supposed to be a variable (i.e. "$serverlink")? It looks like you are intending to pipe a variable string through sed, but are in fact piping the output of wget - in other words, it's your commandline redirection syntax that needs attention (not your regex).

Comment: @AvinashRaj check main post , in the end, there is the input and expected output.

Comment: @Jos, thanks for the repeat , but sorry , i didn't understand how i can done that (i'm newbie with this).

Comment: @steeldriver "serverlink" is the website link , i didn't post it because i don't want to do spam.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you want to extract the URL by parsing the output of the `wget` command (if so, see my answer) or if you are trying to `wget` the parsed URL itself. In which case, see @steeldriver's and also clarify where you have stored the text you want to parse.

Comment: The idea , is get the link of video , and download it. I dont have problem to download it , the problem is getting the link. I only need to get the link of video. In this code , i can get 2 links , but , now testing , i'm getting 2 links from the video (See @terdon answer), but i'm only need one. I wish to explain me more , but i speak spanish , i hope you can understand what i'm saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some simpler approaches to get what you want:

1. `grep` with [PCREs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)

   ```
   wget -q -O - "serverlink" | grep -oP 'flvurl=\K[^;]+(?=&amp;)'
   ```

   #### Explanation

   In PCREs, the `\K` means *"discard everything matched until here"*. The `-o` option to `grep` means *"print only the matched portion of a string"*. So, `grep -oP 'flvurl=\K` means: *"look for `flvurl=` and start matching **after** it."* The `[^;]+` means *"match as many non-`;` characters as possible*.

   The `foo(?=bar)` format is called a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It is not part of the actual matching string. It means _"match `foo` followed by `bar` but discard the `bar`. Putting all this together, the regular expression above will print everything between `flvurl=` and `&amp;`.
2. `sed`

   ```
   wget -q -O - "serverlink" | sed -nr 's/.*flvurl=([^;]+)&amp;.*/\1/p'
   ```

   #### Explanation

   The substitution operator (I use the traditional `s///` instead of the `s\\\` you used but its the same idea), will substitute everything with the text between `flvurl=` and `&amp;`. The parentheses are there to "capture" the matched string, making it available as `\1`. The `-r` option enables [extended regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) which can deal with parentheses without needing to escape (`\(` and `\)`) them. That's the reason you were getting the error by the way.

   The `-n` suppresses normal output, no lines will be printed by default. The `p` at the end of the substitution (`s///p`) means *"print the current line if the substitution was successful"*.
3. Perl

   Using the same logic as the `sed` above:

   ```
   wget -q -O - "serverlink" | perl -ne 's/.*flvurl=([^;]+)&amp;.*/$1/ && print'
   ```

Comment: sorry for posting again , but i'm getting both links from the first box , any chances for only get one ?

Comment: @lucas_7_94 that shouldn't happen, you're probably getting URLs from different lines. To keep only the first one, try `wget -q -O - "serverlink" | grep -m 1 oP 'flvurl=\K[^;]+(?=&amp;)'` or pass the output through `| head -n 1 ` to keep the first line and `| tail -n 1` to keep the last. For more details, you will have to update your question with the actual output of the `wget` command.

Comment: working with "|head -n 1" like a charm. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your command line is piping the output of wget into sed - in order to substitute the **result** of the sed command as a URL **argument** on the wget command line, you will need to do something like

```
wget -q -O- -- $(echo -n "urlstring" | sed -e 's/pattern/replacement/')
```

or

```
wget -q -O- -- $(sed -e 's/pattern/replacement/' <<< "urlstring")
```

The `-e` may be omitted in this context.

Comment: I _think_ the OP wants to parse the actual HTML returned by the `wget` command.

Comment: Oops - should I delete the answer to prevent confusion?

Comment: No! I can't figure out which one of us has interpreted it correctly :). Let's see if the OP clarifies. EDIT: ah, apparently I did, the OP just accepted mine.